# Sails You are not permitted to perform this action

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Hello I am new to sails and making simple login via passport.
sails raise error every time when i try redirect to another page which is accessible only after login.
I put the view in another folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTLbJ.png)

These are the files in which i have made change for authentication

### AuthController.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
module.exports = {
    index: function (req,res)
    {
        res.view();
    },

    passport_local: function(req, res)
    {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info)
        {
            if ((err) || (!user))
            {   
                res.redirect('/');
                return;
            }

            req.logIn(user, function(err)
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    res.redirect('/user/login');
                    return;
                }
                req.session.user = user;               
                res.redirect('/loginq');
                return;
            });
        })(req, res);
    },

    logout: function (req,res)
    {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

### HomeController.js

```
  module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        res.view({
            user: req.user
        });
    },
    testpage:function(req, res) {
    res.view({
      user: req.user
    });
  }

};
```

### passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {console.log("serializeUser :: user.id "+user.id);
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOneById(id).exec(function (err, user) {console.log("deserializeUser");
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: email}).exec(function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + email }); }
            if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }console.log("USERRRRRRR");
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

### routes.js

```
    '/': {
    /*controller : 'home',
    action     : 'index'*/
     view:'home/index'
  },
  '/login' : {
    controller : 'auth',
    action     : 'index'
  },
  '/loginq': {
    controller : 'home',
    action     : 'testpage'## Heading ##       
  },
  '/savesignupdetails': {
    controller: 'user',
    action:'saveDetails'
  },
  'get /user/login':{
      controller: 'auth',
      action: 'index'
  },
  'post /user/login':{
    controller: 'auth',
    action: 'passport_local'
  },
  '/logout' : {
    controller : 'auth',
    action     : 'logout'
  }
```

### policies.js

```
 *': 'sessionAuth',
  'auth': {
    '*': true
  },
  'home' :{
    '*' : 'sessionAuth'
  },
  'testpage' :{   
    '*' : 'sessionAuth'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pay careful attention to the ordering of your policies.js when combining this with the '*' catcher.

I will have a go tonight at mirroring your set up to find the issue but this ordering and usage of '*' is the first place I would be looking:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-policies

Comment: Now it is solved ,actually I made mistake in sessionAuth.js file
Thank You